# excel formula only if all cells are filled if not to show a blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am setting up a results spreadsheet and need this problem solved to create the result below.
A1 = 40
B1 = 50
A2 = 30
B2 = 20

I want if (A1+A2)>(B1+B2) to show "1" in cell C1, only if all the cells are filled, if any cells are not filled to show "0" in C1.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Count() to count the number of values in the four cells. If the count is less than 4, some cells are empty.

I'm not quite sure what formula you want to use when all cells are filled, but the idea goes like this:

```
=if(COUNT(A1:A2,B1:B2)=4,<yourformula>,0)
```

Edit: I think your complete formula would be

```
=if(COUNT(A1:A2,B1:B2)=4,if((A1+A2)>(B1+B2),1,0),0)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, works perfectly for my spreadsheet.

Comment: If that solves your problem, please mark the post as the answer as shown in the [tour](http://superuser.com/tour)